# Cancel requests on route change (React/Redux/Axios)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, axios

Is there convenient way to cancel all sending request on any route changes using `axios`, `redux-thunk`, `redux`? I know that `axios` has cancellation token which should be added to every request and I can call `source.cancel(/* message */)` to cancel it.

P.S. Currently I handle this in `componentWillUnmount`. Maybe there is something better?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way which I found is to store `source` in state, and use `source.cancel` if request is sending.

`componentWillUnmount() { if(isLoading) { source.cancel() } }`

Comment: But they say that storing functions inside store is not good idea.Store should be serializable.You can read about this [here](https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state).Im looking for solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution would be to declare `isMounted` variable and set it to `false` when component unmounts.

Other way of handling this issue is, (I'm not sure about `axios` but) `XMLHttpRequest` has `abort` method on it. You could call `xhr.abort()` on `componentWillUnmount`.
Check it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

And finally there is an industry solution :) from Netflix UI engineers. They have written a redux middleware for RxJS and using RxJS operators to fire up and cancel the requests.

The library is called `redux-observable`. I recommend to take a look at examples: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html

You can watch the talk about it here: https://youtu.be/AslncyG8whg

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution (without redux) to do that. All you need is a **cancelToken** in your axios requests. After, use the **useHook** to **detect route changes**. Then, cancel the requests with the TOKEN when the route is unmounted and to generate a new TOKEN to make a new request. See the Axios Doc to more details (https://github.com/axios/axios).

**Route.tsx file**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, RouteProps, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import API from 'src/services/service';

const CustomRoute = (props: RouteProps) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  // Detect Route Change
  useEffect(() => {
    handleRouteChange();

    return () => {
      handleRouteComponentUnmount();
    };
  }, [location?.pathname]);

  function handleRouteChange() {
    // ...
  }

  function handleRouteComponentUnmount() {
    API.finishPendingRequests('RouteChange');
  }

  return <Route {...props} />;
};

export default CustomRoute;
```

**Service.ts file**

```
import { Response } from 'src/models/request';
import axios, {AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const ORIGIN_URL = 'https://myserver.com'
const BASE_URL = ORIGIN_URL + '/api';
let CANCEL_TOKEN_SOURCE = axios.CancelToken.source();
    
function generateNewCancelTokenSource() {
  CANCEL_TOKEN_SOURCE = axios.CancelToken.source();
}

export const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

const API = {
  get<DataResponseType = any>(
    endpoint: string,
  ): Promise<AxiosResponse<Response<DataResponseType>>> {
    return axiosInstance.get<Response<DataResponseType>>(endpoint, {
      cancelToken: CANCEL_TOKEN_SOURCE.token,
    });
  },

  // ...Another Functions

  finishPendingRequests(cancellationReason: string) {
    CANCEL_TOKEN_SOURCE.cancel(cancellationReason);
    generateNewCancelTokenSource();
  },
};

export default API;
```